# Advanced Probability & Statistics problem

Tags: probability-distributions

How do I solve "assume that X ∼ N (µ = 5, σ = 2), calculate P(X > 7)". Not sure what to do when σ are that high, need to change it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "high"? In any case to calculate the probability it is only necessary $\sigma$ since we are going to take $X$ to a standard normal.

\begin{align*}
P(X > 7) & = 1 - P(X \leq 7) \\
& = 1 - P \left( \frac{X - \mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} \leq \frac{7 - \mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}  \right) \\
& = 1 - P \left( \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{7 - \mu}{\sigma}  \right) \\
& = 1 - P\left( Z \leq \frac{7 - 5}{2} \right) \\
& = 1- \Phi(1) \\
& = 1-0.8413447 \\
& =  0.1586553
\end{align*}
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$

Comment: I was thinking about this all wrong, thanks!